# SSIS column mapping in Data Flow task when number of columns is high

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I know SSIS automatically maps columns in source and destination if the names match. But is there a way to map a large number of columns in SSIS(Data Flow Task) when the source and destination column names are different, apart from doing it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only automated criteria for mapping is by matching name. If the names don't match then the easiest way is by drag and drop on the mapping tab of destination editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can change size of your column in source component by using query, for example use SUBSTRING(YourColumn,1,10) in order to change size of YourColumn in source component (you can check size of your output column in `Source Component\Advanced Editor\Input and output Properties\Source Output\Output Columns\YourColumn`), also you can use `Derived Column` component in order to define new column with new size.

**EDIT:**
You can only map source column and destination column with some data type and some size (**the name of source and destination column not important to mapping**).
If you map two column with different size, SSIS raise a warning, and raise error when convert started, and have a data in source that have size more that destination column.

Comment: I am not talking about changing the size of the column. I am talking about mapping them in the Data Flow task. Is there a way to map a large number of columns in Source and Destination when their names do not match? Sorry for any confusion.